# Lazy load values in paginated datatable using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, jquery

I'm trying to use the [jquery datatable plugin](http://www.datatables.net) in my project. It supports ajax loading of values in the table. But my question is does it support lazy loading of value? means If the table is paginated, can I load data required by each page using ajax when it is requested than load all the values at the startup of the page?

Now what I observed is that all data required by the page is loaded when the table is created. It will create problem if the page has to deal with a huge amount of data and it is not used at that point of time.

If this plugin cannot handle it can anyone suggest any other plugin which will support this requirement. I need a data table which supports pagination and lazy loading of contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using the ajax configuration in the datatable itself. You can find the details [here](http://datatables.net/usage/server-side). The option sAjaxSource is used to specify the ajax source and setting the option bProcessing allows us to configure the system to do all the processing like page loading, sorting and filtering in the server side.

Comment: I am trying to implement lazy loading using jquery datatable. I haven't been able to do so and this answer is not helping. Any clues on how to do it?